# Adicionar variáveis à sessão Auth laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4, autenticação

Tenho a minha sessão Auth, que devolve os dados do utilizador:

```
print_r(Auth::user());
```

Nesta sessão, quero adicionar os dados da empresa associados ao utilizador. No meu model *User*, adicionei o seguinte:

```
public function empresa()
{
    $this->belongsTo(Ewempresa::class,'empresa_id');
}
```

Para ir buscar os dados da empresa, neste caso o campo "`morada_fiscal`", tenho isto:

```
echo Auth::user()->empresa->morada_fiscal;
```

O que acontece, é que a empresa não é colocada na sessão Auth.

O meu model User:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function siteuserlangs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Siteuserlang');
    }

    public function siteusertags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Siteusertag');
    }

    public function validate($input)
    {
        $rules=array(
            'uniqueid' => 'required',
            //'username' => 'required|email',
            'active' => 'numeric',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            //'locale' => 'required',
            //'name' => 'required|min:6',
            );

        return Validator::make($input,$rules);
    }

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'siteusers';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }




    public function empresa()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Ewempresa::class,'empresa_id');
    }


    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

}

?>
```

Estou-me baseando no seguinte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37210848/where-to-add-auth-session-variables-when-the-user-is-logging-in

Comment: Sim, para aceder ao campo "morada_fiscal" da empresa, estou a usar isso que escreveu

Comment: Está certo o nome desse model ? **Ewempresa**, você colocou no Belongs.

Comment: @pc_oc faz assim: `Auth::user()->empresa()->morada_fiscal` por favor? (verifique se tem erro de digitação `Ewempresa::class`). e verifique `return`

Comment: Além disso, falta o `return` na função de relacionamento.

Comment: @Zooboomafoo, o meu model Ewempresa está correcto. Na sessão não é metido nada do Ewempresa

Comment: Qual a versão do Laravel ?

Comment: @Zooboomafoo é a 4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Observações:***

O [link que está usando como referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37210848/where-to-add-auth-session-variables-when-the-user-is-logging-in) tem erros no código não utilize, sempre utilize a [documentação oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3) do [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel)

Faltou o `return` no método

```
public function empresa()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Ewempresa','empresa_id');
}
```

faça

```
echo Auth::user()->empresa()->first()->morada_fiscal
```

Answer (score 1):

Faltou o `return`.

```
public function empresa()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Ewempresa', 'empresa_id');
}

echo Auth::user()->empresa->morada_fiscal;
```

Comment: O Ewempresa é um model e não uma class, ele depois não encontra essa class "Class 'App\Ewempresa' not found "

Comment: Se é o 4.2, então tira o "App\".

Comment: mas se fizer print_r(Auth::user()); não aparecem nenhuns dados do Ewempresa, eles não deviam de aparecer?

Comment: Não. `print_r(Auth::user()->empresa)` devia aparecer.

Comment: se fizer isso ele devolve o array vazio. Quando faço o login, isso não devia ser colocado logo na sessão Auth?

Comment: Já verificou o ID da Empresa ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50830/discussion-between-pc-oc-and-zooboomafoo).

Comment: sim, eles estão relacionados

Answer (score 0):

Faz algo parecido com isso, segue o controller:

```
public function dadosUsuario(Request $request)
    {
        $dadosUsuario = Auth::user();
        $dadosUsuario->vendedor = Auth::user()->vendedor;
        return $dadosUsuario;
    }
```

E o model do usuario é :

```
protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'name', 'email', 'password', 'id_vendedor', 'admin'];

public function vendedor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vendedor::class,'id_vendedor');
    }
```